# How can I Iterate through dynamic json c#?

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm getting a response from an api, but this response could be any type of json.
I need to take the **data** and print it on a csv, is there anyway to convert that json to a dynamic object and iterate it or is there any other way to do it?.

My json response is:

```
{
"A":{
    "B":[
        {
            "C":"data"
            "E":"data"
            "G":{
                "H":[
                    {"I":"data"},
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        },

        {...},

        {...},

        {...}
    ]
}
```

}

and latter it could be

```
{
"A":{
    "B":[
        {
            "C":"data"
            "E":"data"
            "G":{
                "H":[
                    {"I":"data"},
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {"K":[
                        {"w":"data"},
                        {...},
                        {...},
                        {"d":[
                            {"d":"data"},
                            {...},
                            {"d":[
                                {"h","data"},
                                {...},
                                {...}
                            ]}
                        ]}
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },

        {...},

        {...},

        {...}
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: It's not at all clear what the difference between your two structures is, other than the second having more nodes defined. You say you want to convert your JSON to CSV, but the output you're showing is not CSV. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are looking to do. Please also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: ... Lookup JObject

Comment: JSON parsers are "dynamic" by definition. They can read any JSON document. If you use `JObject.Parse` on that JSON string you'd get a JObject back and access its properties by name. What you posted though doesn't look like something that could be represented as a CSV. How do you differentiate rows and columns here?

Comment: Perhaps (?), what you're asking is how to recursivelly flatten the JSON payload into  name/value pairs? And each object is written in a separate line?

Comment: no Im telling that it could be a dynamic json, I don't know what is going to be then I need to take that response, Iterate through objects and array an print all the data like:
data,data,data,data,data,data

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library available to parse json and convert them to CSV

```
string json = @"
{
    ""name"":""John"",
    ""age"":30,
    ""cars"": {
    ""car1"":""Ford"",
    ""car2"":""BMW"",
    ""car3"":""Fiat"",
    ""Country"": [
        ""USA"",
        ""Mexico""
        ]
    }
}";

StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
    .WithJSONPath("$")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
    {
        w.Write(p);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
name,age,cars_car1,cars_car2,cars_car3,cars_Country_0,cars_Country_1
John,30,Ford,BMW,Fiat,USA,Mexico
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.